# Как создать сборку Linux?

Tags: linux

Как создать такую сборку Linux, чтоб при запуске автоматически вводились команды: `cd /neosart/` и `gcc neosart.c`?

P.S. не спрашивайте зачем мне это.

Comment: алгоритм: 1. скачиваете [исходники программы linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux). 2. правите. 3. компилируете. 4. готово!

Comment: @РусланИсаев можно же neosart включить в образ сразу. такое не подходит?

Comment: Редактируйте ~/.xinitrc

Comment: А почему нельзя спрашивать зачем тебе это?